# SQL - Multiple Where in one column

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress

Sorry Guys I was using a different example, instead of using COuntry table from w3school I updated my question and give you the real situation.

Im using wordpress and I want to filter out all posts with multiple categories.

```
`SELECT DISTINCT p.id,p.post_title,p.post_content,t.name,tax.taxonomy from 
 wp_posts as p 
 LEFT JOIN wp_term_relationships rel ON rel.object_id = p.ID 
 LEFT JOIN wp_term_taxonomy tax ON tax.term_taxonomy_id = 
 rel.term_taxonomy_id 
 LEFT JOIN wp_terms t ON t.term_id = tax.term_id 
 WHERE 1=1 
 AND p.post_status = 'publish' 
 AND p.post_title LIKE '%lorem%' 
 OR p.post_content LIKE '%lorem%' `
```

I want to use raw sql because I know that conditions will be longer than that.

Here is what Iam getting
https://d.pr/free/i/mrNHXk

But when I added this

```
`AND t.name = 'CGN'
AND t.name = 'Harmony'`
```

I got no result, iam expecting this
https://d.pr/free/i/0NER1F

Using

```
AND t.name IN ('CGN','Harmony')
```

Will not work because The result must have both 'cgn' and 'harmony', if I added 'cfw' on the condition like

```
AND t.name IN ('CGN','Harmony','cfw')
```

The result post should have those 3 categories

Comment: Clearly the `Country` column value in any single row can't be both "Germany" **and** "USA" at the same time; you might have meant to use `OR`.

Comment: Provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not join directly with the taxonomy tables, but use a subquery and the [exists](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/exists-and-not-exists-subqueries.html) predicate to check whether the tags Harmony and CGN exist for the post.

```
select p.id, p.post_title, p.post_content,
    (select GROUP_CONCAT(t.name) from wp_term_relationships rel 
        inner join wp_term_taxonomy tax ON tax.term_taxonomy_id = rel.term_taxonomy_id
        inner join wp_terms t ON t.term_id = tax.term_id 
        where rel.object_id = p.ID) as terms
from wp_posts as p 
where
  p.post_status = 'publish' 
  and (p.post_title LIKE '%lorem%' OR p.post_content LIKE '%lorem%' )
  and exists (select * from wp_term_relationships rel 
      inner join wp_term_taxonomy tax ON tax.term_taxonomy_id = rel.term_taxonomy_id
      inner join wp_terms t ON t.term_id = tax.term_id
      where  rel.object_id = p.ID and t.name = 'Harmony')
  and exists (select * from wp_term_relationships rel 
      inner join wp_term_taxonomy tax ON tax.term_taxonomy_id = rel.term_taxonomy_id
      inner join wp_terms t ON t.term_id = tax.term_id
      where  rel.object_id = p.ID and t.name = 'CGN')
```

Comment: That works,thank you my only concern is I need to term name on the selected fields so I can use it. How would I be able to add in on the returned fields

Comment: For now I need the post_title,id.content and the term name like from wp_terms, if you may tell me how to add extra fields from that table I can expand the code from there, I appreciate your help :)

Comment: @ChesterProfugo This statement only returns one row for each post. Do you want to have all the terms of the post as an additional information in the row? Or do you want to actually have different result rows for each term? And then only for the terms you were looking for or for all the terms of the post? And why?

Comment: no worries, you've helped me enough, I think this is what I need for now. Thank you so much, including wp_term name is just  a possibility but I can live without that for now. Again thank you

Comment: @ChesterProfugo I have added a subquery to add the list of terms for each post as a column to the result.

Comment: Thank you so much, I've been scratching my head on this problem for 2 days now, you really helped me a lot

Answer (score 2):

you will not get any results of that query. The reason is that the Country value can't be both 'Germany' and 'USA' at the same time (in a logical/propositional way).

Try:

`SELECT * FROM Customers WHERE Country in ('Germany','USA')`

other possibility:

`SELECT * FROM Customers WHERE Country like '%Germany%' or like '%USA%'`

Comment: @ChesterProfugo what if you use operator 'like':
` where t.name like '%Harmony% OR t.name like '%CGN%' `

Answer (score 1):

As stated above, the case where country is both Germany **and** USA shouldn't exist.  It would seem you are looking for:

```
SELECT * FROM Customers
WHERE Country IN ('Germany', 'USA');
```

Using the IN clause with a list will return all rows in the customer table where the country contains *either* Germany or USA.

https://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysql.asp?filename=trysql_select_in2